# how to configure maven to use jar files present on the system to satisfy dependency?

Tags: maven-2, pom.xml

I need to configure the jars in my pom.xml file in my web application in such a way that I need not use the lib folder to store all the jar files.
Please help.

Comment: You need to clarify your question if you expect an answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you really have dependencies which are stored in a lib folder (I assume those jar's don't exist in Central) you can use the system dependency

```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>...</groupId>
     <artifactId>..</artifactId>
     <scope>system</scope>
     <systemPath>PathOnYourSystem</systemPath>
   </dependency>
```

But i assume you mean something different, cause the above will procuce a warning on Maven 3. If you have a dependency which is provided by the Container (for example Tocmat) you can define a dependency as provided.
But the best is to put such dependencies into a local repository manager which i hope you are using ([Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/products.php), [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/), [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/)).

Comment: Thank u for the help. But I need to clarify one more thing. I have a large no. of jar files and if i configure them using dependency tag in pom.xml, my pom.xml is going to be very bulky. Is there any way out to configure them directly through the web but the pom.xml should not be bulky. Please help.

Comment: Yes. Install them into your local repository manager which is the best solution. You only need to give the dependencies not their transitive dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did as u recommended. The build was successful. I have 1 doubt left: How do i minimize the configuration of the dependencies in pom.xml that I am using. I am using 45 jars altogether. Do I need to configure each dependency like how you showed earlier. It will be too bulky then. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Are those 45 jars directly used by your app? Or do you have the cases where a jar is used by an other jar ? Let me explain that with an exmaple. Let us assume you are using Hibernate. so you only define a dependency to hibernate but you don't need to define a dependency to the jars which hibernate uses?

Answer (score 0):

You can mannually add them to your local repository (since it seems that they are not at central).

But the best would be to set up your own (or company) repository to hold them for you.